# MongoDB explain query plan

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with index:

```json
{
    "authorizations.participant.participantId" : 1,
    "authorizations.action" : 1
}
```

I have a query:

```js
db.users.find({
    "$query" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "authorizations" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "action" : "READ" ,
                        "participant.participantId" : {
                            "$in": ["5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a","5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "$explain" : true
})
```

I'm trying to understand the query execution plan:

```json
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor authorizations",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 22,
"nscannedObjects" : 22,
"nscanned" : 23,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 22,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 23,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 0,
"indexBounds" : {
    "authorizations.participant.participantId" : [ 
        [ 
            "5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb", 
            "5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb"
        ], 
        [ 
            "5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a", 
            "5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a"
        ]
    ],
    "authorizations.action" : [ 
        [ 
            "READ", 
            "READ"
        ]
    ]
},
"allPlans" : [ 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor authorizations",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 22,
        "nscannedObjects" : 22,
        "nscanned" : 23,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "authorizations.participant.participantId" : [ 
                [ 
                    "5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb", 
                    "5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb"
                ], 
                [ 
                    "5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a", 
                    "5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a"
                ]
            ],
            "authorizations.action" : [ 
                [ 
                    "READ", 
                    "READ"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"server" : "modi:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
    "works" : 23,
    "yields" : 0,
    "unyields" : 0,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "advanced" : 22,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needFetch" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "FETCH",
            "works" : 23,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 22,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "forcedFetches" : 0,
            "matchTested" : 22,
            "children" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "IXSCAN",
                    "works" : 23,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 22,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : "{ authorizations.participant.participantId: 1, authorizations.action: 1 }",
                    "isMultiKey" : 1,
                    "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['authorizations.participant.participantId']: [\"5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb\", \"5549b3f644ae1e4a5764facb\"], [\"5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a\", \"5549b40444ae1e4a5764fb0a\"], field #1['authorizations.action']: [\"READ\", \"READ\"]",
                    "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                    "dupsTested" : 22,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0,
                    "keysExamined" : 23,
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

As far as I understand it, although I can `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor authorizations"`, doesn't the "nscannedObjects"=22 says the there was a full collection scan? (there are 22 documents in that collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using an older version of MongoDB, the `explain()` output as of 3.0 would look different --- just an aside, since you don't mention the version number.

Your query matched ALL your 22 objects:

```
"n" : 22,
```

so yes, it's a full scan. If you want less objects scanned than you will have to use a query that matches less than all.

Documentation of the meaning of "n":
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/explain/#explain-output-fields-core

> `explain.n`
>
> n is a number that reflects the number of documents that match the query selection criteria.